# Antd - validateFields only checks current form step

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to get form steps to be easily navigable. Users must be allowed to go back by clicking on previous form steps, and go forward if target step and everything in between is filled in and valid.

I got it somewhat working by using something like this but the problem with this one is that validateFields() will only check current step's form. So I can fill in, let's say the first step and jump forward 8 steps because validateFields() only validates the current one and thinks everything is all good.

```js
form.validateFields()
      .then(() => {
        setCurrentStep(step);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      });
```

So I am trying to get `validateFields()` to accept an array which contains every form field name that needs to be checked. However, I could not find any documentation for such implementation and the one below always results in resolve.

```js
const handleStepChange = (step) => {
    // let user go back to previous steps
    if (step <= currentStep) {
      setCurrentStep(step);
      return;
    }

    // let user go forward if everything is valid
    // if not, force user to use "next step" button
    form.validateFields(FORM_FIELDS) // FORM_FIELDS is an array that keeps field names
      .then(() => {
        setCurrentStep(step);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      });
  };
```

And this is how I roughly put together everything:

```js
const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(0);

 const initialSteps = {
    form,
    step: (val) => setCurrentStep(val),
    nextStep: () => setCurrentStep((prev) => prev + 1),
  };

const [steps] = useState([
    {
      title: 'Personal',
      content: <PersonalForm {...initialSteps} />,
    },
    {
      title: 'Details',
      content: <DetailsForm {...initialSteps} />,
    },
    {
      title: 'Contact',
      content: <ContactForm {...initialSteps} />,
    }])


return <Steps
          size="small"
          current={currentStep}
          direction="vertical"
          onChange={(current) => handleStepChange(current)}
        >
          {steps.map((item, index) => (
            <Step status={item.status} key={item.title} title={item.title} />
          ))}
        </Steps>
```

How can I validate make sure to validate each and every form field be it unmounted, unfilled, untouched etc?

Edit:
I also tried tapping in to each step's form obj individually, expecting that each form obj would hold it's own form fields but that did not work either

```js
const handleStepChange = (step) => {
  // let user go back to previous steps
  if (step <= currentStep) {
    setCurrentStep(step);
    return;
  }

  // let user go forward if target step and steps in between are filled in
  const validationFields = [];
  const stepsInbetween = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < step - currentStep; i++) {
    const stepCursor = steps[currentStep + i];
    stepsInbetween.push(stepCursor);
    const stepCursorFields = STEP_FIELDS[stepCursor.content.type.name];
    validationFields.push(...stepCursorFields);
  }
  let isValid = true;
  stepsInbetween.forEach((s) => {
    s.content.props.form
      .validateFields()
      .then(() => {})
      .catch(() => (isValid = false));
  });
  if (isValid) setCurrentStep(step);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `Form` element instead of putting together each field. Ant Design's Form already has built-in data collection, verification and performs validation on every field whether they're touched or not.

This is a skeleton form that implements `Form`. You will want to wrap each field with `Form.Item` and then in the `Form.Item` pass in an object as `rules` with `required=True` being one of the entry. Sounds more complicated than it should so here's a snippet:

```
 <Form {...layout} form={form} name="control-hooks" onFinish={onFinish}>
      <Form.Item
        name="note"
        label="Note"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item
        name="gender"
        label="Gender"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Select
          placeholder="Select a option and change input text above"
          onChange={onGenderChange}
          allowClear
        >
          <Option value="male">male</Option>
          <Option value="female">female</Option>
          <Option value="other">other</Option>
        </Select>
      </Form.Item>
```

Any field wrapped by `<Form.Item />` with `required: true` in its rule will be checked and validated. You can also use set up `rules` to be more complex depending on each field's requirement. An example:

```
<Form.Item name={['user', 'age']} label="Age" rules={[{ type: 'number', min: 0, max: 99 }]}>
   <InputNumber />
</Form.Item>

<Form.Item name={['user', 'email']} label="Email" rules={[{ type: 'email' }]}>
  <Input />
</Form.Item>
```

From its [documentation](https://ant.design/components/form),

> Form will collect and validate form data automatically.

So you will save yourself a ton of custom code just by relying on the `Form` component to handle validation for you based on rules you specify on each `Form.Item`.

#### EDIT 1

Based on additional information from the comments, since you've mentioned you already use `<Form.Item>`, this would help enforce the validation is run when user navigate to other pages through the `useEffect()` hook. If `currentStep` is updated, which it is (through `setCurrentStep`), then run the code within the `useEffect()` body.

```
const MultiStepForm = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    form.validateFields()
      .then(() => {
        // do whatever you need to
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [currentStep]);

  const handleStepChange = (step) => {
    // other operations here
    ...
    setCurrentStep(step);
  };
  ...
}
```

Comment: This is already how I put together forms. Everything is wrapped inside a `Form` and every form item is wrapped with `Form.Item`, each with specific rules and validators. Somehow it only validates current step. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that I am passing an empty `form` item with `Form.useForm()` to each form area which is then passed into each step. Maybe I have to set form fields as well before passing `form` in to components?

Comment: @ÖzençB. sorry, that wasn't stated. I also have a multi-step form using ant design and the form validation works for me. I've edited my answer to include how I implemented it

Comment: No matter what I do `form.validateFields()` only validate current step. I've added more code

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `validateFields` method of the form object only validates the fields that are currently rendered in the DOM.

The following is a workaround:

> Render them all but only make the selected one visible

```
  const formList: any = [
    <FirstPartOfForm isVisible={currentStep === 0} />,
    <SecondPartOfForm isVisible={currentStep === 1} />,
    <ThirdPartOfForm isVisible={currentStep === 2} />
  ];

  const formElements = formList.map((Component: any, index: number) => {
    return <div key={index}>{Component}</div>;
  });

  ...

  <Form ...props>
    <div>{formElements}</div>
  </Form>
```

Then in the components that are the parts of your form:

```
<div style={{ visibility: isVisible ? "visible" : "hidden", height: isVisible ? "auto" : 0 }}>
  <Form.Item>...</Form.Item>
  <Form.Item>...</Form.Item>
</div>
```

**EDIT 1**

The above is an anti pattern though.

- If you really need a multi step form. Then validate on every step and keep the data in the parent component by lifting state up
- If you need multiple "tabs"/ places to fill in fields and avoid one big page with all input fields. Then **use Tabs**, this is they are intended for. And data from tabs that are not selected will still be submitted and validated when you submit the form.